# Electrically determine if a speaker is clipping

Tags: audio

Is there any electrical method of detecting if a speaker is clipping? Will it distort the input signal since it's also backdriving said signal, and that might show up on an oscilloscope?

I'm testing an old "bass shaker", basically a linear transducer that you directly attach to a couch/wall/seat instead of having a speaker cabinet, and my curiosity sparked the question.

Comment: "clipping" is the function of the amplifier output, not the speaker ... the scope will reveal it ... run an experiment ... start with sine wave output at low audio volume and slowly turn up the volume

Comment: Do you mean maybe that you want to detect if the speaker or driver is reaching its maximum extension (physically)?

Comment: besides what jsotola said: assuming your amplifier has infinite headroom and your interested only in the speaker response: I guess recording it with a mic is your most systematic bet. Make sure you attenuate enough using enclosures around the mic, so the mic itself wont be clipped and stays linear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never did that with speakers but with solenoid valves you can. You need to look at the *current* profile.

Explanation: when you drive a valve the stem accelerates to move and that creates an electric signal (since it's metal in a magnetic field). At end of travel it stops (so decelerates) and there is a visible notch in the current profile. It's simply magnetic interaction.

Really fancy coil drivers can sense this and detect if the valve actually opened or calibrate the actual current needed.

The main difference is that the valve actuator goes *inside* the coil so there is a much bigger difference than with a speaker which only floats *above* the coil.

Also from the valve technology you can mechanically check the travel with a dial indicator on the stem, you would put that on the center of your 'cone'